# std::cin statement not working c++

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying to make a converter between Celsius and Fahrenheit but I have a problem. When I run my code end enter "Celsius to Fahrenheit" it is terminated.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string ftc;
    int f;
    int c;
    std::cout << "Celsius to Fahrenheit or Fahrenheit to Celcius ";
    std::cin >> ftc;
    if(ftc == "Celsius to Fahrenheit") {
        std::cout << "(c to f) Please provide input ";
        std::cin >> c;
        f = (c*1.8)+32;
        std::cout << f;
    } else if(ftc == "Fahrenheit to Celsius") {
        std::cout << "(f to c) Please provide input ";
        std::cin >> f;
        c = (f-32)*0.5556;
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `std::getline` when accepting strings from standard input. Not `std::cin`.

Comment: @Ron -- you're essentially right, but to clarify, `std::getline` should be applied here to `std::cin`; the problem in the code is not the use of `std::cin`, but the use of `operator>>`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I agree.

Comment: Just a comment on usability: the code should not insist on the user correctly typing "Celsius to Fahrenheit". Just ask for `'C'` or `'c'` or `'F'` or `'f'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin` will stop reading into `ftc` when it encounters white-space, so it will only read one word. Use `std::getline()` instead. This should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string ftc;
    int f;
    int c;
    std::cout << "Celsius to Fahrenheit or Fahrenheit to Celcius ";
    std::getline(std::cin, ftc);
    if(ftc == "Celsius to Fahrenheit") {
        std::cout << "(c to f) Please provide input ";
        std::cin >> c;
        f = (c*1.8)+32;
        std::cout << f;
    } else if(ftc == "Fahrenheit to Celsius") {
        std::cout << "(f to c) Please provide input ";
        std::cin >> f;
        c = (f-32)*0.5556;
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

Read this for more information: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

if(ftc == "Celsius to Fahrenheit")    try with  single word like

> if(ftc == "Celsius")

Works! this way

Comment: Sure, but requiring the user to misspell "Celsius" is probably not a good idea. <g>

Comment: haha sorry for Typo :D